# I have problem using google OAuth2 with django: GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have an issue with @react-oauth/google npm package.
When I using react app on port 3000 and backend django on port 8000 every thing work's, but after I build react app and using port 8000, I try to log in via google, I get that Erros:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 m=credential_button_library:45 [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.`
I did double check on 'Authorised JavaScript origins' and 'Authorised redirect URIs' (image attached)
but the giving origin are allowed, so whats can be the problem?

I read about similar problems here on the site and also tried CHAT GPT but nothing helped.
This is my configurations:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
]

class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter
    callback_url = ['http://localhost:8000', 'http://localhost:3000', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000', 'http://localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/']  # !
    client_class = OAuth2Client
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Comment the `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` and try with `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True` and if this doesn't work try to remove this `http://localhost:3000` and `http://127.0.0.1:8000` from both ( **CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS** and **GoogleLogin** ) and If the above things doesn't work then try to run your react app on **PORT - 3000** and on the URL just change your port to **8000** and then try.